# Log results to console

Tags: ruby, hash, console

With the following method I am having trouble getting the hash attrs printed out to the console, can anyone point me in the right direction please

```
class FacebookFeed
#Constants
VANDALS_ID = ENV['VANDALS_FB_ID']
FB_ACCESS_TOKEN = ENV['FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN']
FACEBOOK_URL = "https://graph.facebook.com/#{VANDALS_ID}/posts/?access_token=#{FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}"

def get_feed
  uri = URI(FACEBOOK_URL)
  response = HTTParty.get(uri)
  results = JSON.parse(response.body) 
end

def formatted_data(results)
return unless results

 results['data'].map { |m| 

attrs = { message: m['message'], 
        picture: m['picture'], 
        link: m['link'], 
        object_id: m['object_id']
      }.compact #remove entries that are nil
   }
     #PUTS ATTRS DOES NOT WORK FOR ME


end

end
```

Thanks

Comment: what is `results` ? can you add an example ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code snippet you provided is that `attrs` is out of scope when you try to access it. Try declaring `attrs` outside (before) of the map block.

Answer (score 1):

You need declare `attrs` variable outside of `map`

```
def formatted_data(results)
  return unless results
  attrs = {}
  results['data'].map do |m| 
    attrs[:message]   = m['message']
    attrs[:picture]   = m['picture']
    attrs[:link]      = m['link']
    attrs[:object_id] = m['object_id'] 
  end
  attrs
end
```

or more clear use [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) method:

```
def formatted_data(results)
  return unless results
  attrs = {}.tap do |acc|
  results['data'].map do |m| 
    acc[:message]   = m['message']
    acc[:picture]   = m['picture']
    acc[:link]      = m['link']
    acc[:object_id] = m['object_id'] 
  end
  attrs
end
```

And just for tips `compact` method not available in `Hash` in built-in `Ruby`, only in `Rails`.

Comment: would you mind explaining what is happening here please, thank you for your answer by the way.. oh right wasnt aware of that for compact, thanks, though when i do use it if a nil value is returned it is returned as {}

Comment: `compact` avaliable only in `rails`, and explain in variable `attrs` hash accumulator then iterate on results and accumulate data to `attrs`. Look tap documentation is very cool method for this case. In you case you assigment `attrs` variables in iterator scope that not available out of iterator.

Comment: so does this mean that if i only wanted to print out the object_id, i could (from your first example) use puts attrs['object_id'] ?

Comment: @Richlewis yep, inside or outside `map`.

Comment: just noticed something, when i now do puts formatted_data(results) in my get_feed method, i get a list of all the object ids now and not all the key/values in the block

Comment: @Richlewis sorry but i cant understand that you mean, my english very bad (